# iOS - Does application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions execute in main thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, uikit

I am wondering if an iOS app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method executes from within the main thread?

Ultimately I would like to know whether it is safe to put UI code in this method and if I should keep blocking code (like network interactions) out of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is executed on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, You can check the current thread.
 print(Thread.isMainThread) //true